# Azure - Data Factory - New Pipeline Created

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, audit

is there any way to receive a mail (some kind of alert) when someone creates a new Pipeline in a Specific Data Factory?

Something like "user XYZ created a new Pipeline"

Thanks for your inputs,
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

To specify an alert definition, you create a JSON file describing the operations that you want to be alerted on.
Following example creates an alert for Run Completion.
Below JSON will help you to create similar for update alert.

```
   {
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "ADFAlertsSlice",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "East US",
      "properties": {
        "name": "ADFAlertsSlice",
        "description": "One or more of the data slices for the Azure Data Factory has failed processing.",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ManagementEventRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleManagementEventDataSource",
            "operationName": "RunFinished",
            "status": "Failed",
            "subStatus": "FailedExecution"
          }
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "customEmails": [
            "@contoso.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```